# Why are most circular pizza peels designed with holes in metal

Tags: equipment, pizza

I am looking to buy a pizza peel. In the UK, I'm noticing a difference in styles, and was curious if there was a reason more than design

There is the "paddle" design, which is more rectangular and a solid piece of metal

[image]

Almost all of the longer handled circular (rounded) peels seem to have holes in the metal as per below.

[image]

This design seems counter intuitive to me - the dough could easily sink into the hole making it more difficult to slide the pizza off. Not only that, but by having holes, there is less area to be floured before putting the pizza on top of the peel

Given both of the designs are (as far as I know) designed for the same purpose (to transfer the pizza), is there a reason why circular peels with longer handles seem to all have cut outs like the picture above? If any one has used them, does it hinder transfer (or at least, sliding the pizza off)

Comment: You should add links to provide source of the pictures unless you happened to snap these photos yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Chef Pomodoro](https://www.chefpomodoro.com/products/aluminum-turning-pizza-peel) round peel you picture is described by the manufacturer as a ‘turning peel’.

> A turning peel is a must-have to easily rotate the pizza multiple times with precision.

Taking that cue I checked a few more on Amazon and they were mostly described that way.

A Turning Peel is specifically for rotating the pizza while it is cooking. I imagine that the radial slots allow increased friction making it easier to turn the pizza. I don’t think you could use it to put a thin, fresh, homemade pizza into an oven.

One reviewer of the Chef Pomodoro peel says:

> The turning peel worked great and freed up my regular peel so we could keep making pizzas inside while I was cooking them outside.

which indicates a separate function from a peel you would build a pizza on.

Comment: Ah, it's for "rotating" not pulling out ??

Comment: @Fattie I think it’s more that it’s not for putting *in*.

Comment: holes also make the peel lighter and easier to use